# How to create dynamic view just like Adobe Flash Builder in eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am creating a RCP in Eclipse Indigo 3.7. I want an **editor-view link** just like **Adobe Flash Builder Design editor and view properties field** i.e on opening an editor, its related view should also open without changing perspective and on closing editor, view should dispose.

I tried placing placeholders for views in editor but had no luck. 
Also tried adding listener to view part but didn't got satisfactory response.

Please help me with your response.

A code snippet will also be helpful..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *not* tested this, but...

In `createPartControl(...)` you should call `IWorkbenchPage.showView(String viewId, String secondaryId, int mode)` and in `dispose()` you should call `IWorkbenchPage.hideView(IViewPart view)`. The later `viewPart` is the return value from `showView(...)`.

Comment: What seem to be the problem? I don't have any other sugestions.

Comment: Yeah dats an option but I want to create a dynamic view like the one in Adobe Flash Builder.(The design view of builder).

Comment: I understand, but I just wanted to make sure that the view itself was available and without errors that prevented the editor to show it :-) Can you attach the exact code that shows the view?

Comment: The one in createPartControl method ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36643/discussion-between-tonny-madsen-and-richa)